# Qt Instances ID change at each run

Tags: qt, testing, automation, ui-automation

I am testing an application using Qt.

I am researching into doing some automation testing, the only problem is that, as far as I can see, either programming it (using AutoIT) or using some other suite, the instances of the objects change at each run.
So, for example, if at run#1 the button 'Next' has instance 0002 at run#2 it might have 0004.

This makes it impossible to have an automation which doesn't rely on mere screen coordinates (with obvious drawbacks).

A way is to use the text/caption instead, but sometimes some object might simply not have one, or not be unique.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

N.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [QTestLib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html):

> The QTestLib framework, provided by Nokia, is a tool for unit testing Qt based applications and libraries. QTestLib provides all the functionality commonly found in unit testing frameworks as well as extensions for testing graphical user interfaces.

It adds the `QTest` namespace which contains several functions for testing QtGui applications including:

- [`keyClick`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtest.html#keyClick) - Send a keyboard key
- [`mouseClick`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtest.html#mouseClick) - Send a mouse click
- [`qWaitForWindowShown`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtest.html#qWaitForWindowShown) - Wait for a window to appear

Comment: But what I would like to have is also some sort of 'record' feature. It basically records all your interactions with the application and saves them; they can be replayed at will.
It would work, except for the fact that QtCLASS instances change everytime.